# How to maintain trutstore separately for ssl server started using openssl ..?

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

suppose i want run with ssl server with following certs

**cacert,

sub-cacert,**
server-cert

For that if i use the openssl s_server to start ssl server by giving options as Cert-( server-cert) CAcert-**(sub-cacert,cacert)** sothat to display the entire chain when client connects

Here my question is that

will be **sub-cacert,cacert** automatically considered as trusted  for my server...??

i mean if client sends the chain like (client-cert,**sub-cacert,cacert**) will the certificate verification results success for client..??

if so how can i avoid this..?? i want to maintain separate trustore using openssl like in java

(as per my understanding in java ,client recieves the chain of certs which resides in the keystore but the server doesn't use these during verification and uses  truststore only for verification  )

Is there any wrong in my assumptions ..???

Thanks in Advance :-))

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the application you are using for SSL (Tomcat, WebLogic, Custom, etc.).

But generally, if you provide the client a server cert and the full chain of certs, and the client trusts the root cert in that chain, then the client will trust the server cert.

The same should apply the other way as well (client to server).

Comment: you mean it places only root cert as trusted..?and ignores subca..?                presntly i am using openssl                                         if i provide cafile then client  able to get chain from server which is desirable case for me but in openssl cafile taken as trusted certs which need discarded for me. i done want to be them as trusted for my serve

Comment: If you are using [openssl s_server](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_server.html) with the -CAfile option, it will use this to send the chain of certs to the client and it will also use this as a trust chain to authenticate the client's cert.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sub-cacert and cacert will be trusted.

I don't have openssl immediately accessible right now to test this, but have you tried manually building your certificate chain?

Ensure that your server identification certificates are in PEM format, and then copy them to a single file in the following order:

```
cert
sub-cacert
cacert
```

(I am assuming that sub-cacert is the intermediate and cacert is the root)

or more generally

```
server identity certificate
intermediate certificates
root certificate authority
```

Where each certificate in the chain must be issued by the certificate directly beneath it, and you can have multiple intermediate certificates.

Try using this concatenated file as your server certificate, and placing only those certificate authorities that you trust for client certificates in the CAfile/CApath.

I don't have must experience with openssl s_server, but I know several applications that use openssl for certificate operations that allow you to do this.

Comment: i dont want to be trusted in my server..the reason why i need to keep the cacert  and subca in CA is to pass the chain to client .. is there any way to pass chain to client instead of put them in CA ....??

Comment: It may be possible to manually build the chain using the certificates you don't want to trust as I have stated, thus keeping them out of your CA file / path.  Try it and see!